# How to save two videos from front and rear camera in a single video file using Camera2 API in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I want to display front and rear camera in single screen and want to record the screen and it should create only one video file in gallery.
I have searched for it and found like we can do it using Camera2 API but not finding any proper documentation on it like how can we start and where can we start

Answer (score 2):

This requires quite a bit of scaffolding.

1. First, not all devices support using the front and back cameras as the
   same time; it's only guaranteed by devices that list support for [FEATURE_CAMERA_CONCURRENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager?hl=en#FEATURE_CAMERA_CONCURRENT).
2. Second, you need to composite the two video streams into one, to display it and record it. There's lots of ways you could do this, but the most performant and straightforward one is probably to use OpenGL ES. If you don't know EGL, it's a lot to learn, unfortunately.
3. You'll need two [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture?hl=en) objects, one for each camera's output. You'll be using them to configure one output for each camera, and then you'll read from their associated texture IDs inside EGL for rendering.
4. You'll need two EGL render targets, one that'll render to the screen (such as a SurfaceView or TextureView) and one that'll send rendered frames to a video recorder.  For the video recorder, you'll need to use MediaRecorder or MediaCodec instance, both of which can give you a Surface object you can create an EGL image from.
5. You'll need to set up the display UI and the media recording objects, and then also the two cameras.
6. Then you need to write and run EGL shader code for every frame that comes out of the camera pair.  This render code needs to do something like:

   1. Wait for both SurfaceTextures to report a new frame available.
   2. Update the SurfaceTextures (`updateTexImage()`)
   3. Target the display EGL image; run the shader code
   4. Target the recording EGL image; run the shader code again
   5. Go back to step #1
7. And there you go - once you have all this infrastructure working, you can make the shader code more fancy (add effects, do picture-in-picture, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your response,
can you please provide any sample code for this