# Android record video from multiple cameras and composite the multiple videos into one video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, camera, android-mediacodec

Android Camera2 records video from multiple cameras, adds real-time timestamps to the frames captured by each camera, and finally composites the multiple videos into a single video file. does Android's native interface support these features? Do I have to user FFMPEG to handle the frames captured by each camera

Comment: Question is similar to: [How to save two videos from front and rear camera in a single video file using Camera2 API in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72660304/295004)